# recognize object on the image and take it out

Tags: image-processing, azure-cognitive-services

I have the image with some object on it - person, vehicle, building or some manually set object. For example assuming I have this image

[image]

I want to take out a house from it

[image]

Can I achieve that using Microsoft Cognitive API and Azure though some custom vision service? Or I should go OpenCV route and others...

Answer (score 1):

You want object detection and segmentation. For that check out the excellent work done by Kaiming He et al:

- [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870)
- [Code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Detectron)

Their work (Mask R-CNN) has also been ported to TensorFlow.

- [TensorFlow Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/CharlesShang/FastMaskRCNN)
- [Mask R-CNN on Python 3, Keras, and TensorFlow](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN)

[image: Demo]